# Is this Green function in interacting fields a contradiction?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, interactions, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

In this book, V. Parameswaran Nair's *[Quantum Field Theory: A Modern Perspective](https://quark.phy.bnl.gov/%7Episarski/talks/Nair.pdf)*, Springer

I saw on page 60 that the two-point correlation function is the Green function of the Klein–Gordon equation (that is the free field Feynman propagator):

$$ i(\square+m^2)G(x.y)= i\delta(x-y)$$

though we are talking about interacting fields. Why is that? Does it have anything to do with dealing with interaction picture?

In addition on page 59 I also saw that the author arrived at (5.23) apparently substituting the correlation function by the free field Feynman propagator. It goes from:

$$G(x_1,x_2,…)= \int dz_1 dz_2 … \ G(x_1,z_1) G(x_2,z_2)…  \ V(z_1,z_2…)$$

To

$$G(x_1,x_2,…) = \int dz_1 dz_2 … \ \sum_k u_{k_1}(z_1) u_{k_1}^*(x_1)  u_{k_2}(z_2) u_{k_2}^*(x_2) … \ u^*_{k_{n+1}}(z_ {n+1})u_{k_ {n+1}}(x_ {n+1})… \ V(z_1,z_2…) $$

(Here the author assumes, from $x_1$ to $x_n$, that $x^0$ goes to $\infty$ and, from $x_{n+1}$ to $x_N$, that $x_0$ goes to $-\infty$ and $u_k$ are supposed to be the free wave solutions)

So, my question is, why does it seem we are dealing with free fields though we are in an interacting context?

Comment: Your question is by no means self-contained. Include the relevant equations and possible quotes.

Comment: Two-points functions are related to all terms that are quadratic in the fields in the action. Interaction terms are all at least cubic in the fields. A free theory essentially contains no cubic or higher-order terms. So, the propagator for both theories are the same by their definition.

Comment: Of course, interactions will cause corrections to the free-field propagator.

Comment: So, if they cause corrections, is it possible that the interacting propagator is still the green function of the Klein-Gordon equation as it is stated in the book?

Comment: I mean, isn’t the G(x,y) above the correlation function in interacting theory?

Comment: I believe $G(x,y)$ here is the indeed the free-field one and is the Green's function. In the interacting case, the corrections to the propagator can be resummed into a renormalised mass. The expression itself will look the same. This is in perturbative QFT of course.

Comment: So G(x,y) is in the free case but $G(x_1,x_2,…,x_n)$ is in the interaction case? And will the interaction propagator be also the green function of free Klein-Gordon equation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142580/discussion-between-guliano-and-marc-barcelo).